# How can I get passwordless ssh from machine to it-self?

Tags: ssh

Passwordless ssh from ubuntu 20.04 machine to itself is now failing after multiple tries and resets.

I have set this up many times, but now it seems to fail with public key denied errors, and I don't understand it.

I've had to mess with setting the cyphers before. Don't think that is it though.

Key is produced via `ssh-keygent -t rsa` and `ssh-add <keyfile>`.

```
cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -v '#'  | grep -v '^$'
```

outputs

```
PermitRootLogin no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

```
cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config | grep -v '#'  | grep -v '^$'
```

outputs

```
Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

```
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-add -D
ssh-add id_rsa
ssh localhost
```

```
we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Authentications that can continue: publickey
we did not send a packet, disable method
No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the steps that you took including generating the key and getting it onto the server. I can tell right away that one of the reasons that it's failing is because you have Password Authentication disabled and you'll need it enabled to cop the public key to the machine.

Comment: @NasirRiley I am on the machine and want to ssh to the machine from the machine. There is only one machine. I can turn on password authentication and it works. 

This *used* to work, I just changed something in the ssh_config or sshd_config and do not understand the errors messages or something now.

Comment: I'm wondering about "we did not send a packet, disable method" ... what does that actually mean?

Comment: And is there anything in the ssh_config (client) that could be messing this up?

Comment: I believe your public key (probably `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) is missing in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: Why do you need to ssh into a machine that you're already logged into?

Comment: You should check the syslogs to see if sshd is logging the reason for the authentication failure. Also, could you run `ls -la .ssh` and then [edit] your question to include the output?